# unable to create step definitions for scenario outline features

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber

I am facing rather a strange situation here. I am unable to create a step definition for the scenario outline features in intellij. Alt+Enter wouldn't work and there is no lightbuld drop down either. the moment i remove the double quotes and greater than and less than symbols (pardon my jargon here, I couldn't find any other words to explain them), the lightbuld appears again. quite strange really. not sure if the 2017 intellij update has caused this. 
any help much appreciated!

```
Scenario Outline : test logins 

Given I am logged in as "<user>"

Examples:

|User|
|person1|
|person2|
```

When I click on the Given, I don't see the yellow bulb
And clicking Alt+Enter wouldn't give any options to create step definitions
. however, if i were to remove the `"<  >"` the yellow bulb appears and clicking Alt+Enter works fine.

Comment: Please edit the question to show a specific code example where the feature does not work.

Comment: Hi Yole! I have edited the question to include the code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It may be because you need "<User>" instead of "<user>"

Comment: I have this kind of thing happen as well. For some unknown reason it might work later on (shitty plugins maybe?) Anyway there is always the easy way: Run your test. It will fail and in the logging suggest you implement the test with a code snippet. Copy and paste. Does not solve your problem, but you'll at least be able to easiliy do your job :)

Comment: thanks for the input guys! a quick quick investigation revealed that this issue is only effecting features under certain directories (I have feature files spread across different directories). need to investigate further.